# How to modify Actionbar's default selected color in android 4.0 + ?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to modify Actionbar item's default selected color in android 4.0 + ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a cool tool ActionBar generator http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/